# Виджет для подключения к каналу telegram

Tags: php, wordpress, telegram

Стоит задача сделать данный виджет, [image: виджет для телеграма]

Я смотрел API телеграма и там есть только 2 вида виджетов: пост и авторизация. Мне нужно именно такое же окно как на ссылках по типу: *t.me/any_channel*, только виджетом на сайте(на wordpress, к примеру). Не могу найти готовых решений, а костылять не хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже вот то, что Вам нужно https://wordpress.org/plugins/tgchannel/ 
- плагин для Wordpress
Или можете собрать тут tgwidget.com

Comment: Спасибо, но tgwidget не дает возможность сделать такой виджет(раньше мог), и к тому же, он пропускает через свой сайт все редиректы от кнопки.

Comment: В таком случае, нам нужен только вывод и количество участников, а кнопку можно запилить прямой ссылкой

Comment: Осталось участников подтянуть))

Comment: а это уже как 2 пальца...